# I need to see where my sharedpreferances values are stored

Tags: java, android-studio, sharedpreferences

In my project, I need to see the location of my shared preference where can I see it.

Comment: Can we see the code that accesses these "shared preferences?"  I'm not sure what you're referring to by that name.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are stored in an XML file in the app data folder, i.e.

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
```

or the default preferences at:

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml
```

SharedPreferences added during runtime are not stored in the Eclipse project.

Note: Accessing `/data/data/<package_name>` requires superuser privileges

Answer (score 0):

Go to device File explorer at the right bottom of your android studio. From there go to data-> data->(your package)->shared preferences